# How to define class-methods with metaprogramming?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Why is the following not creating class-methods?

```
class Movie
  ['upcoming','now_playing','top_rated'].each do |method|
    define_method(method) do |page=1,api_key='xxxxxx'|
      movies = get("/movie/#{method}",:query=>{page: page,api_key: api_key}).to_hash["results"].map{|m| Movie.new(m["id"])}
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Your title and your question don't seem to match, and your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just replace [`define_method`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-define_method) with [`define_singleton_method`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-define_singleton_method).

Answer (score 1):

Because `define_method` creates an instance method, not a class method.